# ObjectDataSource in c# Code Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datasource, objectdatasource

Is it possible to read the data provided by an ObjectDataSource created in code behind? Take the following for instance:

```
ObjectDataSource myObjectDataSource= new ObjectDataSource();
myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(new SessionParameter("createdDate", TypeCode.String, "FilterCreated"));
```

How could you then get the rows from this? For example in a Dataset you would do something like:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in myDataset.Tables[0].Rows) {
     string abc = dr["myColumn"];
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps. But there is a method named "Select()" which returns an IEnumerable which you can use and iterate the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this , convert objectdatasource to dataset and than read that

```
private DataSet ConvertObjectSourceToDataSet(ObjectDataSource ods)
{
   var ds = new DataSet();
   var dv = (DataView)ods.Select();
   if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
   {
     var dt = dv.ToTable();
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
   }
  return ds;
}
```

Code source : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/how-to-bind-dataset-with.html

Comment: I have to say that you are awesome! Superb answer and one I will definitely be reusing in the future I'm sure +1 :-)